# How do I create an alias for a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, alias

Normal way:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a.b.c = 10

    def another_method(self):
        self.a.b.c = self.a.b.c * 10
```

Aliased approach:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a.b.c = 10         
        alias self.aliased = self.a.b.c  # Creates an alias 

    def another_method(self):
        self.aliased = self.aliased * 10  # Updates value of self.a.b.c
```

How does one accomplish aliasing in Python? The reason I want to do this is to reduce cluttering due to long variable names. **It's a multi threaded environment**, so simply copying to a local variable will not work.

Comment: Your code is not valid Python code at all, and I don't understand the semantics of the notation you use.  As an example, what is `self.a.b.c.d.e = 10` supposed to do?  What is `self.a` supposed to be after running this line?

Comment: Why do you have (too) long variable names in the first place? And if you are really doing nested attribute access deeper than two levels, there is something serious wrong with your design.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The solution to this is to use getter and setter methods - fortunately Python has [the `property()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) to hide the ugliness of this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a.b.c = 10

    @property
    def aliased(self):
        return self.a.b.c

    @aliased.setter
    def aliased(self, value):
        self.a.b.c = value

    def another_method(self):
        self.aliased *= 10  # Updates value of self.a.b.c
```

Generally, deeply nested attributes like `self.a.b.c` are a sign of bad design - you generally don't want classes to have to know about objects that are 3 relationships away - it means that changes to a given item can cause problems throughout your code base. It's a better idea to try and make each class deal with the classes around it, and no further.

Comment: A property like this also adds indirection which *really hurts* performance. It's like orders of magnitude slower than just setting the attribute directly.

Comment: @nosklo Obviously there is overhead, but that really doesn't matter in most cases.

Comment: the statement "indirection is orders of magnitude slower" is extremely dubious and requires support.

Answer (score 4):

Python doesn't copy anything implicity, it only stores references so it will work no matter which environment you're in.

```
# this creates a list and stores a *reference* to it:
really_really_long_variable_name = [] 
# this creates another new reference to the *same list*. There's no copy.
alias = really_really_long_variable_name

alias.append('AIB')
print really_really_long_variable_name
```

You'll get `['AIB']`

Comment: the problem is `alias = ['BIB']` will not update `really_really_long_variable_name`

Comment: Agreed, this doesn't solve the problem of updating the value unless you use a mutable container as a hack.

Comment: @ie. of course, you don't update variables. You update the mutable object. If you use the chars `[]` then you're creating another object...

Comment: Well, there are lots of times when you need to use a builtin function that returns a different reference. This solution breaks as soon as that happens.

Comment: A caution note for those who read "Python doesn't copy anything implicity" too literally: `a = 1; b = a; a = 2; print(b)` is `1` and `a = 1; b = a; b = 2; print(a)` is
`1`. Re-assigning to a variable does not update the other variable.